# Vue using the same directive twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

I have global directive to hide modal when user click out:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind(el, binding, vNode) {
    el.clickOutside = event => {      
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
            vNode.context[binding.expression](event);
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutside)
  },
  unbind(el) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutside)
    el.clickOutside = null
  }
});
```

Next I have use this directive:

```
<img src="noti.png" id="1" v-click-outside="onClickOutside('notification')">

<img src="dots.png" id="2" v-click-outside="onClickOutside('profile')">
```

I have problem because I cant use this same directive on one component. Vue retururn me erro:

```
vNode.context[binding.expression] is not a function
```

I found this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771602/why-does-using-the-same-vue-directive-multiple-times-call-updates-on-all-of-them), but the answer not help me.
When add `console.log` to directive and click for example on first `img` directives will be done twice.

How I can detect (in directive) which `img` was clicked ?

Comment: You are checking opposite action - which img isn't clicked. 
To catch img click event, use just v-on:click

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need to do` el == event.target` and `el.contains(event.target)`, you can just use `contains()` as  will return `true` for descendant of a given node including itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains.

Answer (score 0):

The value you pass to custom directives will be evaluated straight away when the template is rendered. This is unlike `v-on` which has special behavior by the Vue template compiler which will automatically wrap it in a function.

I explain this in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288137/conditionally-bind-custom-directives-in-vue-js-for-clicking-outside-an-element/50288393#50288393).

I don't know if this will completely fix your problem, but at least you need to do something like this:

```vue
<img src="noti.png" id="1" v-click-outside="() => onClickOutside('notification')">
```